# Get Unique Keys from a dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am  new to spark. I have a spark dataframe:

```
print(df)
[Row(feature=Row(a=u'enabled', b=None, c=None, d=u'enabled', e=None, f=None)),
     Row(feature=Row(a=None, b=None, c=None, d=u'enabled', e=None, f=None))]
```

I am trying to get all feature names in a list

```
experiments = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

I have tried:

```
a = df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.feature).collect()
```

This gives me all key, value pairs.

ie.

```
[Row(a=u'enabled', b=None, c=None, d=u'enabled', e=None, f=None), Row(a=None, b=None, c=None, d=u'enabled', e=None, f=None)]
```

How can I get distinct features as list after the above step or is there any other elegant solution?

i.e

```
final_list = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Rdd_name.keys()` is what you need if you are working with an RDD.

As explained the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.columns), `df.columns` is what you need to get the list of columns in a Spark dataframe.

You can also access the keys by converting a Row to dictionary as follows:

```
>>> df 
[Row(feature=Row(a=u'enabled', b=None, c=None, d=u'enabled', e=None, f=None)), Row(feature=Row(a=None, b=None, c=None, d=u'enabled', e=None, f=None))]
>>> df[0]
Row(feature=Row(a=u'enabled', b=None, c=None, d=u'enabled', e=None, f=None))
>>> df[0].asDict()
{'feature': Row(a=u'enabled', b=None, c=None, d=u'enabled', e=None, f=None)}
>>> df[0].asDict(True)
{'feature': {'a': u'enabled', 'c': None, 'b': None, 'e': None, 'd': u'enabled', 'f': None}}
>>> df[0].asDict(True).keys() 
['feature']
>>> df[0].feature.asDict(True).keys() 
['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f']
>>>
```

Comment: It says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: @SpaceOddity because somewhere in your code you converted your dataframe to a list.. the sample `df` is a list. Check my updated answer for another way to access the keys from your list.